# How to update image file in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update an image of a database (One-To-Many and Belongs-To Relationships)
i have table proposition with fields id, proposition. 
now the proposition table has relations with image table like this

**image module**

```
public function proposition()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Proposition');
}
```

**proposition module**

```
public function propositionimage() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PropositionImages');
}
```

now i want to update the image  to an proposition:
i want to get the old value of input file and change it with the new value of input file . 
the probleme is whene i use this

```
$proposition = Proposition::find($num_proposition);
$image = $proposition->propositionimage()->get();
```

it showing all the image of the proposition 
i want to update all the image but one by one , any help plz ?

the HTML code

```
<img src="/images/{{ $propositonimage->imagename }}" alt="">
<div class="caption">
    <input type="file"  name="image" value="{{$propositonimage->imagename}}" >
</div>
```

the update function

```
public function update(PropositionRequest $request, $num_proposition)
{
    $proposition = Proposition::find($num_proposition);

    $image = $proposition->propositionimage()->get();
    // echo "$image";

    $images = Input::file('image');
    if (Input::hasfile('image')) {
        $rules2 = array('image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png');
        $validator2 = Validator::make($images, $rules2);
        if ($validator2->passes()) {
            $distinationPath = 'images';
            $imagename = $images->getClientOriginalName();
            $upload_success = $images->move($distinationPath, $imagename);
            $extension = $images->getClientOriginalExtension();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what the problem is. But it seems as you want to iterate the collection over the div?

**proposition model**

```
public function propositionimage()
{   
   return $this->hasMany(PropositionImages::class);
}
```

**image model**

```
public function proposition()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Proposition::class);
}
```

Then you return a view with `proposition` in a controller, and eager load `PropositionImages`?

```
public function index(){
   $propositions = \Proposition::with('propositionimage')->get();
   return view('image', compact('propositions'));
}
```

You will have a collection of proposition with corresponding images.

```
@forelse ($propositions as $propositon)
  <img src="/images/{{ $propositon->imagename }}" alt="">
    @if($propositon->propositionimage->count())
      <div class="caption">
        @foreach($propositon->propositionimage as $propositionimage)
        name: {{$propositionimage->imagename}}<br>
            <input type="file"  name="image" value="{{$propositionimage->imagename}}" >
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @else
        No proposition image <br>
    @endif
@empty
  No images :(
@endforelse
```

Please add more details to your question otherwise.

**Edit**
I tried this at my local dev machine and it works.
All relations of `propositionimage` will be iterated to the corresponding `proposition`.